# Checkout Cart page shows 503 error

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, quote

I am using Magento 2 website. I got the error like following when redirecting to checkout/cart page.

Once deleted all the products in cart and tried to add all the products again and its seems to be no error there.

May I know, what can be issue. I can't track the issue.

> {"0":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add
>   or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`stateofh_magento2`.`quote_shipping_rate`, CONSTRAINT
>   `QUOTE_SHIPPING_RATE_ADDRESS_ID_QUOTE_ADDRESS_ADDRESS_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`address_id`) REFERENCES `quote_address` (`address_id`) ON DELETE C),
>   query was: INSERT INTO `quote_shipping_rate` (`address_id`, `carrier`,
>   `carrier_title`, `code`, `method`, `method_description`, `price`,
>   `method_title`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)","1":"#0
>   /chroot/home/stateofh/hockeylodge.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)\n#1
>   /chroot/home/stateofh/hockeylodge.com/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303):

Comment: I think using google chrom please change and use mozilla firefox I think this issue is solved  then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact solution for this. Yet, I came to a conclusion. Only one specific user got that error. Those are all the products which are added with a long time before. Because of that, there may be any misconfiguration between old Shiping Methods / Payment methods which is currently not available in the site.
Once I deleted that customer and recreated it, I tried to add as many products as I did before. Thankfully, it works fine.

If anyone finds a better solution or conclusions, you can share here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I delete the quotation on **quote** table related to the customer, and than relogin, so it works fine.